# C++/ Help me understand the logic

Tags: c++, math

I was told to solve this problem:

> given a1, ..., an are real numbers. Need to calculate min(a1, -a1a2, a1a2a3, ...,(-1)^(n+1) a1a2,... an)

but I cannot understand the logic of the task. Could you tell me what I should do?

For example, what is `(-l)^n+1`? I've never seen it before.

Comment: What do you think what does this question says?

Comment: Put all the `an` in a vector. Then use nested loops over the vector to calculate each product, and put these in another vector. You can put a coefficient in a variable that alternates between `1` and `-1`. Finally find the minimum value of the result vector.

Comment: Have you had algebra in school yet?

Comment: @Spencer They are having C++ classes before algebra LOL

Comment: Why would you need a nested loop?

Comment: That shouldn't be `-l`, it `-1`. It means negative 1 raised to the power of `n+1`. Which is the mathematical way of alternating between `1` and `-1`.

Comment: It's "minus one" not "minus ell". It shows that the sign of each term alternates.

Comment: `^` probably stands for the _power operator_, note that in c++ this operator means something completely different.

Comment: @Darth-CodeX In that case, OP should find a math teacher in school and ask for help.   Because you should understand the problem (thus the math) before ever trying to start coding it.

Comment: The terms are `a1`, `-a1*a2`, `a1*a2*a3`, `-a1*a2*a3*a4`, `a1*a2*a3*a4*a5`, ... Do you see the progression? There is no need to raise `-1` to any power: it can be a simple multiplier that alternates between `+1` and `-1`, which can be achieved in each loop with `multiplier *= -1`

Comment: Note:  for each term, you are using a new digit to multiply the previous product.  Such as `(a1), (a1 * a2), ((a1 * a2) * a3)`.  You can use a temporary variable in the loop to contain the *previous* product, thus reducing the need for another loop. :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is:

- use the n real numbers of input to ...
- ... calculate the n numbers defined by the quoted formula (though you only need one value at a time to be more efficient)
- while doing so keep track of the smallest number you encounter, that is the final result
- concerning the `(-1)^(n+1)`, it is reasonable to assume (as e.g. in the comment by Weather Vane and others) that it means powers of -1 (in a lazy and unexplained but non-C++ syntax)
- note that you can easily calculate one value from the previous one by simple multiplication
- probably you should do all of that by writing a program, an assumption based on the fact that you are asking on StackOverflow and tag a programming language